# how to fix system.typeinitializationexception error

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, typeinitializeexception

I'm using mysql2000.
The code as below:

```
Dim MyConnection As SqlConnection
MyConnection = New SqlConnection(Parameters("DBConnectionString"))
MyConnection.Open()
```

Parameters.xml:

```
<add key="DBConnectionString" value="Initial Catalog=database; Data Source="localhost";User ID=sa; password=sa" />
```

The error message shown when it runs

```
MyConnection = New SqlConnection(Parameters("DBConnectionString"))
```

I have found a lot of solutions but those doesn't work for me.
Its work fine when i run at testing server but not at server 2.
Anyone can help? thanks so much.

Comment: Make sure the connection string is correct. Do you have it anywhere else and working?

Comment: i can use these userid and password to login the database.

Comment: But maybe the server name, database name, format or something of the connection string has a typo or it's wrong.